# How to filter results in Flutter package flappy_search_bar?

Tags: flutter

From what I read in the [package documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flappy_search_bar#-readme-tab-) ,
the "searchBarController" parameter should allow to filter the results, but I can't find any documentation. I also read through the package content but can't find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in the example file, which shows how to us the SearchBarController : https://github.com/smartnsoft/flappy_search_bar/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart